# Shared Preferences android basic question

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, data-storage

I save a user's username and passwords the first time he opens the app and store it in a SharedPreferences object. I check for the data the second time he enters and if its not null, then I got into the app. Here is how I'm doing this:

```
private SharedPreferences dhj;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dhj = this.getSharedPreferences("DHJ", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    if(dhj.getString("username", null) != null) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
            // do some stuff...
    }
    else {
            setContentView(R.layout.login);
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
                    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor dhjEditor = dhj.edit();
                    dhjEditor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
                    dhjEditor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                }
            }); 
                    // do some other stuff...
    }
}
```

But each time I open the app, I am being asked to enter the username and password. 
What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the desired functionality?
Thank you.

Comment: can you post the code where you store the password and username please?

Comment: how are you saving the username/password in preferences?

Comment: Your not showing were you save the username and password into the SharedPreferences. tbh your problem probably is your not calling .commit();

Comment: Thank you. @Blundell I think thats the problem. I have posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the Editor's `commit` method after making any change to preferences.  This will save the preferences file:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor dhjEditor = dhj.edit();
dhjEditor.putString("username", username.getText().toString());
dhjEditor.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
dhjEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way, is my code for checking if the user has already entered login info correct?

Comment: looks fine, although if the user doesn't enter anything and clicks the login button it will be seen as logged in.  empty strings will be saved as username/password.  you may want to do some validation before saving to prefs

Comment: @binnyb You stole my answer? :-(

Comment: i knew the answer, i was waiting for him to further explain his question. i don't see your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `editor.commit()` function is a synchronous function that performs a file system operation. Calling this from the main thread (your code seems to run in the main thread) might - in unfortunet situations - throw a ANR since file system operations might stall and thereby block the main thread.

I would use the `editor.apply()` function instead, since it will immediately update the in-memory cache of your shared preferences and then create a worker thread and write the values to your shared preferences file from there (worker threads don't block the main thread).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Answer (score 2):

The doc of "getSharedPreferences" says:

*Desired preferences file. If a preferences file by this name does not exist, it will be created when you retrieve an editor (SharedPreferences.edit()) and then commit changes (Editor.commit()).*

Make sure you use the same editor for all writing before committing, e.g.

```
Editor editor = mPref.edit();
editor.putString("username", username);
editor.putString("password", password);
editor.commit();
```